# ¿Cuál es el origen de "santabárbara"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

Ayer leyendo un libro apareció la voz *santabárbara*, que según el DLE es:

> **[santabárbara](https://dle.rae.es/santab%C3%A1rbara)**
>
> 1. f. *Mar*. Pañol o paraje destinado en las embarcaciones para custodiar la pólvora.
> 2. f. *Mar*. Cámara por donde se comunica con la santabárbara o se baja a ella.

En el DLE como voz independiente aparece desde 1817, pero aparece también en el *Autoridades* de 1737 en otra entrada:

> RANCHO DE SANTA BARBARA. Se llama la division que está debaxo de la cámara principal del navio, donde está la caña del timón.

Casos existen en el CORDE desde el siglo XVII al menos:

> *Su alojamiento es vajo del alcázar o en el rancho de santabárbara entre los artilleros, si es capellán del galeón; y si es de la ynfantería, entre ella en su alojamiento.*
>
> Tomé Caño, "Diálogo entre un Bizcaýno y un Montañés sobre la fábrica de navíos", 1631 (España).

Antes de 1600 ya solo encuentro menciones a Santa Bárbara (virgen y mártir). Entiendo que habrá alguna conexión entre la santa y el pañol de pólvora, pero ¿cuál es? ¿De dónde le viene exactamente el nombre de *santabárbara* a esta parte de las embarcaciones?

Comment: Is it by any chance related to SB being the patron saint of artillerymen?

Comment: @mdewey it could perfectly be.

Comment: En la wikipedia se indica que: "Recibe este nombre por la imagen de Santa Bárbara, patrona de los artilleros, que generalmente está colocada en este lugar." https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santab%C3%A1rbara

Comment: @RubioRic ya me ha vuelto a pasar, consulto todas las fuentes de información de la RAE y no encuentro nada, se me olvida mirar en la Wikipedia de toda la vida y resulta que la respuesta estaba ahí. Estaría bien confirmarlo, en el [Diccionario Marítimo Español](https://books.google.hn/books?redir_esc=y&hl=es&id=DT4Kzd55sKkC&q=santabarbara#v=snippet&q=santabarbara&f=false) de 1831 que se referencia no dice nada al respecto en la entrada de Santa-Bárbara.

Answer (score 2):

Just so we get a proper answer for this rather than just comments. Saint Barbara is the patron saint of artillerymen and miners, professions which use explosives. She is also recognised as a protector against thunder and lightning from circumstances surrounding her martyrdom. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A1rbara_de_Nicomedia

As the link supplied by RubioRic https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santab%C3%A1rbara confirms an image of her would be placed near the gunpowder store for protection against accidental explosions.